# how to count the number of documents with specific initials in ubuntu?

Tags: bash, shell

say I have files in an ubuntu folder as following

```
~/folder$ AA001.jpg AA002.jpg BB001.jpg CC001.jpg
```

Rookie as I am, thinking about using `xargs` to pass the specific initials to count the files as following,

```
AA 2 BB 1 CC 1
```

after trying, now I can get the answer individually,

```
ls *.jpg|cut -d "0" -f1| grep -c "AA"

2
```

how can I get all the answers all at one line command?
Thanks for advices.

Comment: None of this is Ubuntu-specific. I have assumed your shell is Bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you think you need `xargs`?

```sh
for prefix in AA BB CC; do
    printf '%s %i\n' "$prefix" $(printf '%s\n' $prefix* | wc -l)
done
```

The nested `printf` is slightly complex; to see more clearly what's going on, try

```sh
for prefix in AA BB CC; do
    printf '%s ' "$prefix"
    printf '%s\n' $prefix* | wc -l
done
```

If you only want to count `$prefix*.jpg` matches, obviously then do that instead.

This will still produce incorrect results if some of the matched file names contain newline characters.  If you really need to cover all bases, try

```sh
for prefix in AA BB CC; do
    printf '%s ' "$prefix"
    printf '%s\0' $prefix* | grep -z -c .
done
```

The `-z` option is a GNU extension, but you are specifically asking about Ubuntu, which comes with the GNU utilities, so just remember that this might not be portable to other platforms.

In the general case, to get a count for all two-character prefixes, try

```sh
declare -A count
for file in *; do
    ((count["${file:0:2}"]++))
done
for prefix in "${!count[@]}"; do
    printf '%s %i\n' "$prefix" "${count[$prefix]}"
done
```

This requires Bash version 4 or newer (which should be installed on a reasonably fresh Ubuntu).

I'll also point out that [you should not use `ls` in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); see the linked article for details.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I am thinking of xargs for not actually knowing what the initials will be. It generates by itself. so I need to pass the filenames to something which can cut off the rest and make the initials as filters.

Comment: Besides, I will try (and try to understand), and report how it goes. thanks!

Comment: The last script shows how to loop over all files and extract the first two characters from each.